# Why am I getting strange ComboBox behavior?

Tags: c#, combobox, dpi

I have a comboBox in my print menu that allows the user to set print DPI. Instead of starting the SelectedIndex count at 0, I'm having to start it at 
-1 for the comboBox to return correct values.  Why would this happen? I tried some suggestions from here, including setting a default SelectedIndex value, but that did not solove the problem.

```
    private void toolStripComboBoxPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (toolStripComboBoxPrint.SelectedIndex == -1) dpi = 96;
        if (toolStripComboBoxPrint.SelectedIndex == 0) dpi = 200;
        if (toolStripComboBoxPrint.SelectedIndex == 1) dpi = 300;
        if (toolStripComboBoxPrint.SelectedIndex == 2) dpi = 600;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(dpi);
    }

    private void printPreviewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBoxMain.Image != null)
        {
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(dpi);
            Bitmap myBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBoxMain.Image;
            myBitmap.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);
            printDocument1.DocumentName = myBitmap.ToString();
            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDialog1.Document;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Label1 and Label2 only return the correct values when I start counting at 
-1. Why?! Thank you

Comment: You mean that with this code: if (toolStripComboBoxPrint.SelectedIndex == -1) dpi = 96; when user select first item(which equals to index 0) then dpi is being assigned to 96 ?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. That's what I can't undersdtand!

Comment: Did You try to debug it ? Set a breakpoint on first if -> choose first element and check wchich condition is satisfied

Comment: Is it standard ComboBox or some kind of user control ?

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep the breakpoint in mind, although I have tried it already. It's a standard comboBox inside a menu.

Comment: It's REALLY strange - User Can't select item at -1. You can just do this in code which is equals to Nothing is selected

Comment: @MajkeloDev Could you please comment on whether any of the proposed answers solved your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Please read about the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` property [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This property indicates the **zero-based** index of the currently selected
>   item in the combo box list. Setting a new index raises the
>   `SelectedIndexChanged` event. `SelectedIndex`, `SelectedValue`, and
>   `FormattingEnabled` are related as follows:
>
> - If `FormattingEnabled` is `false`, `SelectedIndex` will **not** be set to **-1** when `SelectedValue` is **blank**.
> - If `FormattingEnabled` is `true`, `SelectedIndex` will be set to **-1** when `SelectedValue` is **blank**.

So, if your question is why is my `SelectedIndex` value `-1`?

It is because `SelectedValue` is "blank" and you have `FormattingEnabled` set to `true`.

But it appears your problem is caused by the fact that you are binding to the incorrect event, namely the `OnClick` event, instead of the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

What happens, is that your `Click` event handler is called **before** the `SelectedIndex` property of the combo box changes. So you are looking at its **old** value.

To solve this remove the `toolStripComboBoxPrint_Click` event handler and replace it with

```
private void toolStripComboBoxPrint_SelectedIndexChanged(
    object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedIndex = toolStripComboBoxPrint.SelectedIndex;
    if (selectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (selectedIndex == 0) dpi = 96;
        if (selectedIndex == 1) dpi = 200;
        if (selectedIndex == 2) dpi = 300;
        if (selectedIndex == 3) dpi = 600;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(dpi);
    }
    else // no dpi selected, what to do?
    {
        // You will need to figure out what you want to do here.
        label1.Text = ""; // Empty?
    }
}
```

And bind this event handler to your combobox instance when your form is constructed like:

```
this.toolStripComboBoxPrint.SelectedIndexChanged += 
        new System.EventHandler(toolStripComboBoxPrint_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get combobox from their value. Selected index start from 0.

Comment: Yes, that's what's strange.  THIS comboBox only works right if I start the index at -1.